# Css pseudo element curve background positioning

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I am trying to do a challenge from frontend mentor where you have some div elements with curve images on top and bottom. I am trying to do it with before and after pseudo elements like this

```css
.feature__item {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 200px 0;
    padding: 50px;
}

.feature__item-1::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 139px;
    background-image: url('../images/bg-section-top-desktop-1.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -139px;
}

.feature__item-1::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 139px;
    background-image: url('../images/bg-section-bottom-desktop-1.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -139px;
}
```

The element located at the bottom does not create a problem. But the top element crashes when I play with the width of the browser. Is there a way to make bottom of the `:before` element sit on top of the parent div? Or is there another way to fix this?

Comment: `background-position:bottom` for the before element?

Comment: Yeah, totally absolutely true!!!  Thank you so much